# Circularly shifting nested vectors

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

Given a nested vector A

```
[[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]]
```

my goal is to circularly shift rows and columns.

If I first consider a single row shift I'd expect

```
[[7 8 9] [1 2 3] [4 5 6]]
```

where the 3rd row maps to the first in this case.

This is implemented by the code

```
(defn circles [x i j]
     (swap-rows x i j))
```

with inputs

```
(circles [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]] 0 1)
```

However, I am unsure how to go further and shift columns. Ideally, I would like to add to the function circles and be able to either shift rows or columns. Although I'm not sure if it's easiest to just have two distinct functions for each shift choice.

Comment: if ```(def v [1 2 3 4])```, then ```(rest (conj v (first v))``` equals ```[2 3 4 1]```. doesn't solve your whole issue but might be a starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defn circles [xs i j]
  (letfn [(shift [v n]
            (let [n (- (count v) n)]
              (vec (concat (subvec v n) (subvec v 0 n)))))]
    (let [ys (map #(shift % i) xs)
          j  (- (count xs) j)]
      (vec (concat (drop j ys) (take j ys))))))
```

Example:

```
(circles [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]] 1 1)
;= [[9 7 8] [3 1 2] [6 4 5]]
```

Depending on how often you expect to perform this operation, the sizes of the input vectors and the shifts to be applied, using [core.rrb-vector](https://github.com/clojure/core.rrb-vector) could make sense. `clojure.core.rrb-vector/catvec` is the relevant function (you could also use `clojure.core.rrb-vector/subvec` for slicing, but actually here it's fine to use the regular `subvec` from `clojure.core`, as `catvec` will perform its own conversion).

Comment: Where is shift defined? I am seeing it a lot, but cannot find its definition anywhere?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus In this snippet, it's a local function introduced by the `letfn` form – `(letfn [(shift …)] …)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [cycle](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/cycle):

```
(defn circle-drop [i coll]
  (->> coll
       cycle
       (drop i)
       (take (count coll))
       vec))

(defn circles [coll i j]
  (let [n (count coll)
        i (- n i)
        j (- n j)]
    (->> coll
         (map #(circle-drop i %))
         (circle-drop j))))

(circles [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]] 2 1)
;; => [[8 9 7] [2 3 1] [5 6 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a function for that called `rotate` in `core.matrix` (as is often the case for general purpose array/matrix operations)

The second parameter to `rotate` lets you choose the dimension to rotate around (0 for rows, 1 for columns)

```
(use 'clojure.core.matrix)

(def A [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]])

(rotate A 0 1)
=> [[4 5 6] [7 8 9] [1 2 3]]

(rotate A 1 1)
=> [[2 3 1] [5 6 4] [8 9 7]]
```